# AngularJS: How to change URL parameter without using reloadOnSearch and not to reload controller using ui route?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to change URL query parameter without reloading my controller. And I can't use `reloadOnSearch`  property, because it does not meet my other requirements.

For Example: `Path: /score?interval`

i want to change `interval` value without using reloadOnSearch and controller should not be reload.

Can this be done with Angularjs? And, if so, then how?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/gMfyX0hKNMQFvZWgHMCw/preview). It uses Angular's $location service to change the URL without reloading the controller. You can use this method to update URL parameters also:

```
$location.path('/test/item/' + $scope.itemId);
```

If you want to change just the URL parameters you can do this as shown in this [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/gMfyX0hKNMQFvZWgHMCw/script.js). (Preview in windowed mode to see it working) You can use $location.search() to do this as shown below:

```
$location.search('id', testId);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: $location.path is used for changing path, not for query parameters!! Or may be i am wrong??

Comment: Thanks!! But this is working, if i dont defined `interval` parameter into `$stateProvider` config. But then i cant get value using `$stateParams`.

Comment: Are you wanting to reload the controller so you can keep the $scope.scoreId and $scope.interval variables updated? Or is there another reason?

Comment: If `$scope.scoreId` value changed ,then controller must be reload and want updated `scoreId` and `interval`. But if `$scope.interval` value changed, then dont want to reload controller , only change into url.

Comment: But that is the reason you want to reload the controller? Just so you can update $scope.interval and $scope.scoreId?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63473/discussion-between-shivali-patel-and-leon-revill).